# XUL: Printing value from SQL query without using value attribute

Tags: sql, sqlite, xul

I want to print the results of an SQL query in XUL with word-wrapping using the description tag. I have the following code:

```
    <grid>
    <columns>
        <column flex="2" />
        <column flex="1" />
    </columns>

    <rows datasources="chrome://glossary/content/db/development.sqlite3" ref="?" querytype="storage" >
        <template>
            <query>select distinct * from Terms</query>
            <action>
                <row uri="?">
                    <description value="?name" />                        
                    <description value="?desc" />
                </row>
            </action>
       </template>
  </rows>
```

This works for printing the data, but since I'm using the value attribute of description, there's no word-wrapping. I don't understand entirely what I'm doing with the value attribute, but I don't seem to be able to get the values of my SQL query in any other way. So, how could I get those values without the value tag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, if anyone's ever looking, I found this out on IRC:

You can use a textnode element to do this.

```
<description><textnode value="?name" /></description>
```

This will give you line-wrapping.